# iOS - Group array of objects by time not by date

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, datetime

I got array of objects which has one property time.
I want to group objects by time like ( 1pm - 2pm , 2pm - 3pm , 3pm - 4pm).

I got my object array from today date only using this following code:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrent

//TODAY
let targetData = locs.filter({
        $0.date?.toDate != nil && calendar.isDateInToday(($0.date?.toDate)!)
})
```

**Challenge:**
My next challenge is to separate my array by time .

I don't think we got method like date for group by today, tommorowy, yesterday.

**I want the todaysdates array to filter based on time range ( like 1pm - 2pm) **

Any pseudocode or algorithms.

Regards.

Comment: Do you want to sort the array by time or what do you mean by "separate my array by time"?

Comment: @RashwanL: I want to filter my todaysdate array by time range . ( 1pm - 2pm ) data only ...

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @RashwanL:
no i haven't yet

Comment: Do you want to create a new array with all the dates only?